# Use C++ camera_info_manager yamls with camera_info_manager_py, and vice versa?

Tags: ros, python, rospy, camera-info-manager

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd like to run [camera_info_manager_py](http://wiki.ros.org/camera_info_manager_py) saveCalibrationFile in a python file and then load the same yaml in in C++, but it appears the yaml dump is saving like this:

```
!!python/unicode 'camera_matrix':
  !!python/unicode 'data': [1059.8847344712244, 0.0, 636.6932553292625, 0.0, 1058.8956875577258,
    470.30001700247, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
!!python/unicode 'camera_name': camera
!!python/unicode 'distortion_coefficients':
...
```

as opposed to the cleaner C++ output:

```
image_width: 640
image_height: 480
camera_name: image_publisher
camera_matrix:
  rows: 3
  cols: 3
  data: [500.0, 0, 320, 0, 500.0, 240, 0, 0, 1]
distortion_model: plumb_bob
distortion_coefficients:
...
```

Loading the C++ yaml in python doesn't generate an error, but the camera info is blank, while loading the python yaml in C++ generates

```
[ERROR] [/cam/image_pub1] [/tmp/binarydeb/ros-jade-camera-calibration-parsers-1.11.10/src/parse_yml.cpp]:[221] [Exception parsing YAML camera calibration:
yaml-cpp: error at line 0, column 0: bad conversion]
```

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong on the python side?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227392/use-c++-camera_info_manager-yamls-with-camera_info_manager_py,-and-vice-versa?/) by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 8729 on 2016-02-23

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It might be a bug. I doubt anyone has actually tried that test, certainly not me. Thanks for the report.

If you don't mind, please [open a github issue](https://github.com/ros-perception/camera_info_manager_py/issues/new), explaining exactly how your Python program uses `camera_info_manager_py` to save the data, and which Python version you are using.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2016-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2016-02-24**:
I'll do that https://github.com/ros-perception/camera_info_manager_py/issues/7

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2016-02-27**:
Follow-up: it is a bug, and thanks to @lucasw for providing a fix.